# Can't clone git repo on windows when some file names contain asterisk

Tags: windows, git

I have files with the following name in my repository:

`*.example.com.crt`

The thing is that I can't clone the repository on windows.

`error: unable to create file *.example.com.crt (Invalid argument)
Checking out files: 100% (6122/6122), done.
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.`

Do you know any workaround for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Windows [disallows certain characters in the filename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx), and Git will support just about anything, so it's up to you to manage it.  I think your best solution is to simply rename the file.

Personally, I'd avoid using `*` in a filename anyways, since it's a glob character.

Comment: this is a particular problem when the file is in the wiki repo. There is no way to rename the file from the repo web page, and no way to rename it from git bash since you cannot check the wiki out. - The only solution I see in this case is to check out on a linux machine to rename the file. I hope someone has another solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround if your repository is on GitHub, you can launch Visual Studio Code IDE right in the browser. Just open your repository in GitHub and press `.`. In the browser, you should be able to modify even the files with asterisks in their filenames.

Comment: Actually, it seems that VSCode will not load even in the browser on Windows if there are any invalid chars such as the asterisk in repository filenames, so this workaround won't work.