# Error cloning a repository on Windows due to invalid chars in file name

Tags: windows, git, github

When I want to clone repository that contain : (colon) in the path I got this error:

> Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.

I tried to use git cli and git gui and I got same error.
Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't clone git repo on windows when some file names contain asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780189/cant-clone-git-repo-on-windows-when-some-file-names-contain-asterisk)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bwindows%5D+Clone+succeeded%2C+but+checkout+failed

Comment: Rename the file in a different OS, push, clone/pull/checkout.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clone from GitHub and if it's your repository, you can edit file content and rename them right on GitHub.

Click on the file you want to edit and you will see at the beginning of a file:

[image: Github_edit_example]

Click on the **pen** icon, rename file and below type commit message and commit. Then you can try to clone.

*NOTE*: If it's not your repo, try to fork it first then do the same steps mentioned above.

Comment: I use my Linux computer to clone and change folder names and then copy it back to windows.

Comment: Hi @EldinZaimovic if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.