# git bash Client for window not able to clone my repository

Tags: git, git-bash

This is first time I am using git bash of window on my desktop to try to clone my project repository. Here is the screen shot of my running, and it failed.

[image]

I guess the root cause is there is such file in the repository tree, which can not be handled by this git.

```
.../(-inf,4.2.2.291)|[4.2.3.517,7.0.0.0)|[7.0.1.0,+inf).jinja2
```

As the same command works fine on my UBUNTU Server.

Does anyone know how to solve that issue. I have just shifted to work in my window environment.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26780319/7976758 (esp. see [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780189/cant-clone-git-repo-on-windows-when-some-file-names-contain-asterisk/26780319#comment122891547_26780319)). Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+succeeded+checkout+filed

Comment: Note that Git *can and did* **clone** the **repository**. What Git cannot do is *check out that particular commit*, because it has a file name that Windows disallows.